# Telerik - export to excel

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I am trying to use the export to excel feature in telerik rad grids using the following code:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top">
    <CommandItemSettings  ShowExportToExcelButton="true"></CommandItemSettings>
    <Columns>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="WordID">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    </Columns>
</MasterTableView>
```

And on the page load in the code behind i am assigning the radgrid the datatable. Is there something else i am missing as when i click the button, it just reloads the page and doesnt do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

It is just **a button**. In order to export your grid into the Excel, you have to, actually, implement it. Here is my implementation of excel exporting, hope it helps:

```
public void ExportToExcel(RadGridView grid, string name)
    {
       string extension = "xlsx";
            if (name == null)
            {
                name = "NewWorksheet";
            }
            SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog
            {
                DefaultExt = extension,
                Filter = String.Format("{1} files (.{0})|.{0}|All files (.)|.", extension, "Excel"),
                FilterIndex = 1,
                FileName = name
            };

            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                using (Stream stream = dialog.OpenFile())
                {

                    grid.ExportToXlsx(stream,
                        new GridViewDocumentExportOptions
                        {
                            ShowColumnFooters = true,
                            ShowColumnHeaders = true,
                            ShowGroupFooters = true,
                            ExportDefaultStyles = false,
                            AutoFitColumnsWidth = true
                        });
                }
            }
    }
```

And FYI, don't expect Telerik to do anything, automatically for you. It's not really, what this framework does (which surprised me too).

Comment: Yes, this is 5 years old, but I just needed to do it now. I assume `grid` is the name of the RadGrid? I'm using VB.NET, and the ExportToExcel method only has two overloads, one with nothing, and one with the GridExcelExportFormal enum.